# LibGDX, flappy bird clone, creating BUTTON

Tags: java, android, button, libgdx, flappy-bird-clone

I am developing a flappy bird clone, and I really got stuck with this button that I want to create. I am sorry, I know this is a basic question, but I am beginner and I really need your help. So, the game is pretty much finished, but instead of touching all over the screen for a bird to jump, I want to make a button that will do the same thing. Here is my InputHandler class:

```
public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor {

private Bird myBird;
private GameWorld myWorld;

// Ask for a reference to the Bird when InputHandler is created.
public InputHandler(GameWorld myWorld) {
    // myBird now represents the gameWorld's bird.
   this.myWorld = myWorld;
   myBird = myWorld.getBird();
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    if (myWorld.isReady()) {
        myWorld.start();
    }

    myBird.onClick();

    if (myWorld.isGameOver() || myWorld.isHighScore()) {
        // Reset all variables, go to GameState.READ
        myWorld.restart();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
}

}
```

I created a stage and an actor (button) in GameScreen class (it is not working), and it shows on screen, but I don't know what to do next. Again, I am sorry for such a basic question, but I really need your help to finish this game.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

private OrthographicCamera cam;
private int gameHeight;

Stage stage;
TextureAtlas buttonAtlas;
TextButtonStyle buttonStyle;
TextButton button;
Skin skin;
BitmapFont font;

SpriteBatch batch;

private GameWorld world;
private GameRenderer renderer;
private float runTime;


// This is the constructor, not the class declaration
public GameScreen() {

    float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    float gameWidth = 544;
    float gameHeight = screenHeight / (screenWidth / gameWidth);

    world = new GameWorld();
    renderer = new GameRenderer(world, (int) gameHeight, (int) gameWidth);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputHandler(world));
}


@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    runTime += delta;
    world.update(delta);
    renderer.render(runTime);

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 544, gameHeight);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    stage.act();

    batch.begin();
    stage.draw();
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    System.out.println("GameScreen - resizing");
}

@Override
public void show() {
    System.out.println("GameScreen - show called");

    stage = new Stage (Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);

    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/font.fnt"), false);

    skin = new Skin();
    buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas ("data/button.pack");
    skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);

    buttonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    buttonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button");
    buttonStyle.over = skin.getDrawable("button - Copy");
    buttonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("button - Copy");
    buttonStyle.font = font;

    button = new TextButton("" ,buttonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button);

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    System.out.println("GameScreen - hide called");
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    System.out.println("GameScreen - pause called");
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    System.out.println("GameScreen - resume called");
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // Leave blank
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much get rid of anything that references general touch input. Once you've done that, you need to make your button's `OnClick()` method call the method that "bounces" the birdie. If you've given this function a method of it's own, it should be relatively easy.

To pull away from "doing it for you", I'll show you an example in C#:

```
boingButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bird.Bounce();
}
```

And the bounce method as such:

```
Bounce()
{
    bird.Height += 4;
    bird.Descend();
}
```

This would be assuming you have a method for the bird's descent. The advantage with the button is that ideally you shouldn't need any overloads for it's method, although I may be wrong with Java.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfish's idea is right. Translated into Libgdx framework would look as follows:

```
    btnBounce.addListener( new ClickListener() {             
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            bird.bounce();
        };
    });
```

Comment: The idea was to get the guy to do that part him/herself. There's a bit too much "do for" and not "teach" here.